# CacheAutoConfiguration is not working due to CacheAspectSupport not found

Tags: spring-boot, spring-cache

I'm using springboot 2.1.1.
I enabled cache with @EnableCaching

A CacheManager is created and can be injected in my classes.

Once I add a library https://github.com/MarcGiffing/bucket4j-spring-boot-starter
I've got an error when starting the application :

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: No CacheResolver specified, and no bean of type CacheManager found. Register a CacheManager bean or remove the @EnableCaching annotation from your configuration.
at org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheAspectSupport.afterSingletonsInstantiated(CacheAspectSupport.java:227)
```

After a lot of debugging, I can't find why and how the library is breaking the CacheManager.

It seems like the CacheAutoConfiguration spring class is not used :

```
   CacheAutoConfiguration:
  Did not match:
     - @ConditionalOnBean (types: org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheAspectSupport; SearchStrategy: all) did not find any beans of type org.springframework.cache.interceptor.CacheAspectSupport (OnBeanCondition)
  Matched:
     - @ConditionalOnClass found required class 'org.springframework.cache.CacheManager' (OnClassCondition)
```

But I added a breakpoint in ProxyCachingConfiguration#L63 and an instance of CacheInterceptor (CacheAspectSupport impl) is created.
I can inject it in one of my Configuration class. So the bean CacheAspectSupport seems to exist in the application context.

So why the CacheAutoConfiguration says the bean is missing ?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found out why.

My `Configuration` class holding the `@EnableCaching` annotation was loaded too late when the library was added.

I added a `@AutoConfigureBefore(CacheAutoConfiguration.class)` and It is now working.